# Validation and Faces Messages are not displayed

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

I have the following form in a `p:outputPanel`

```
<h:form id="someForm">
    <p:panel id="panel" header="HEADER">
        <h:panelGrid columns="5">

            <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />

            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{userBean.name}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="ASD" label="name" maxlength="15">
                <f:validateLength minimum="10"></f:validateLength>
                <p:ajax event="blur" update="inputValidationMessage" />
            </p:inputText>

            <p:message id="inputValidationMessage" showDetail="true" for="name"
                display="icon" />
            <p:watermark for="name" value="e.g Jill" />

        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="panel"
            actionListener="#{userBean.doSomething}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

I expect that when the `inputText` element loses focus and its content has a length less than 10 characters, the message `ASD` is displayed right next to it. However, what happens in case validation fails is, only a red cross icon is displayed. The message `ASD` is missing. Changing `showDetail` to `showSummary` doesn't work neither.

Secondly, the `commandButton` calls `userBean.doSomething`:

**UserBean#doSomething:**

```
public void doSomething(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                                          "Summary",
                                          "Detail"));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        context.addCallbackParam("booleanVar", true);
}
```

The FacesMessage is not being displayed.

I'm using JSF2.0 with Primefaces 3.0 on Weblogic 12.1.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the `<p:message>` as follows:

```
<p:message ... display="icon" />
```

Here's a cite from the `<p:message>` documentation in the PrimeFaces [User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_0.pdf):

> #### Display Mode
>
> Message component has three different display modes;
>
> - text : Only message text is displayed.
> - icon : Only message severity is displayed and message text is visible as a tooltip.
> - both (default) : Both icon and text are displayed.

So the message severity is displayed as icon and message text is only displayed as tooltip of the icon. You need to *remove* the `display="icon"` so that it will show both in view.

```
<p:message ... />
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC. Validation message are now displayed. But what about the `FacesMessage` returned from `userBean.doSomething`. It still doesn't show?

Comment: That's a different question. But ala, those with `null` client ID will only be shown in a `<h/p:messages>` or `<p:growl>`, but I don't see any in your code. They will however be logged to the server log like as `WARNING: a FacesMessage has been enqueued but was not displayed`. In the future, please ask separate questions in separate questions.

Comment: Then how do I specify a non-null clientId? There is no such attribute? I assigned an `id` to the button and added another `p:message` for that id, with no luck. Would you like me to carry this to another question or could you just do a quick update on your answer? :)

Comment: You need to specify the client ID (as you see in generated HTML output) in `addMessage()`, not the component ID (as you specified in XHTML source). Just add a `<h/p:messages>`. It's the canonical way for displaying global messages anyway.